# nested Magnific AJAX pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nested, magnific-popup

I'm using magnific-popup and I'm trying to call AJAX popup inside the main pop-up. I can do the nesting part if both pop-ups are inline so I can place second pop-up container outside the first one.. but The problem in AJAX is I can not place the response outside the main div so it gets hidden

Here's an example where client_view is the main popup and it has ajax-pop-up nested

```
<a href="#client_view" class="pop-up">Client view</a>
<div id="client_view">
   <a href="createClientAjax.php" class="ajax-pop-up" >Add Client</a>

 </div>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this right now.

Dimitri (the creator) said he would not do this, as it is too complicated and no really useful. http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/details/hwIng

Maybe something like this will do:
 https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/36